# Generate all possible combinations with recursion

Tags: python, c, recursion, combinations

I want to generate all possible combinations using recursion, came up with a solution in python but don't know how to implement it in C.

```py
def combinations(text):
    if "?" in text:
        for char in "abc":
            combinations(text.replace("?", char, 1))
    else:
        print(text)
combinations("???")
```

Which gives us all possible combinations of length 3 using **abc**.

My **C** code looks something like this but it does not work as it should be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char chars[4] = "abc";

void combinations(int repeat, char *result){
    if (repeat--){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            result[strlen(result)] = chars[i];
            combinations(repeat, result);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("%s\n", result);
        result[0] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(){
    char *res = (char *)malloc(2000);
    combinations(3, res);
}
```

What I expect is that it outputs every possible unique combination of length 3 using *abc*:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
...
```

What *C* code outputs are:

```
aaa
baa
caa
baaa
...
```

Comment: Why not `#include <string.h>` and use `strlen` instead of home-baking `len`?

Comment: @Stef, yes, the `const` keyword *should* be used, to clarify intent and help catch implementation errors, but there is no risk of crashing without it as long as the implementation in fact does not attempt to modify the string.  It would be different in C++, but there the risk would be of compile errors, not runtime crashes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've been buried in so much python these past days, for a second there I actually forgot real programming languages are compiled :'(

Comment: You only need 4 characters (not 2000) if you do it on-line with backtracking unless you intend on *saving* the results?